# Can I get predictions from Winbugs/OpenBUGS?

Tags: winbugs

I am new to WinBUGS and OpenBUGS. I just ran an example model, and am wondering whether I can get the predictions generated by WinBUGS/OpenBUGS. If not, is there any convenient way to achieve this (e.g. with the help of other applications such as R)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. In Bayesian tools, it is very easy to get predictions. In your design matrix, just add new rows, with response variable set to NA. You can see [concrete example here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31554/5509).